# Doorbell Transformer?

Tags: transformer, doorbell

Looking to update our transformer so we can install the Nest Hello. I believe I found it but wanted to verify if this looks correct?[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What do you mean by "update our transformer"? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a transformer. It is a simple junction box with 3 cables.

This is what a doorbell transformer looks like. Notice the brown cable on the right. That is the type of cable you should be looking for to locate your transformer.

[image]

Comment: That is great, I’ll keep looking. Thanks for the quick answer and helpful picture!